# radius add nas record to nas table fail

Tags: mysql, radius

my compony has a radius that was used to auth, now I want to use that to strongswan vpn , and after I config the strongswan,I config the radius that add  nas table a record    like

```
 10 | 172.16.2.10  | hlg-vpn   | other |  NULL | testing | NULL   | NULL      | RADIUS Client |
```

and ok, the 172.16.2.10 is the ipaddress of the strongswan server, and the nas table also contain others nas records those work fine .

the record I add to nas table seems doesn't work. when I auth the vpn with  a radius  account, the radius log is like

```
Sat Jun 24 20:34:45 2017 : Error: Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 172.16.2.10 port 48394
Sat Jun 24 20:34:47 2017 : Error: Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 172.16.2.10 port 48394
Sat Jun 24 20:34:50 2017 : Error: Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 172.16.2.10 port 48394
Sat Jun 24 20:34:54 2017 : Error: Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 172.16.2.10 port 48394
```

I'm new to radius, am I lose config something after add a nas record to nas table?  could someone tell me why , thanks..

something else,  I am sure the other nas record in the table work fine, because , the config seems true, and I don't find any other config like those nas records in the raddb directory, also, I google it , the config file sql.conf point out that nas table is in use.

Comment: Did you restart Radius after updating the nas table? Radius only reads in the nas table during start-up, if you change/edit it you need to restart radius.

Answer (score 0):

On the RADIUS server you need to define a list of RADIUS clients the server will accept packets from.

There are two reasons you need to define clients:

- RADIUS packets use a PSK (Pre-Shared key) for encrypting certain attributes and preventing packet modification.  For security, each client should use a different PSK. The client definitions associate different secrets with different client's IP addresses.
- Processing RADIUS packets can sometimes be expensive in terms of the load on backend databases.  It's useful to define ACLs which drop RADIUS packets before any processing is done.  In FreeRADIUS unless an IP address is matched by a client definition the packet will be discarded.

Client definitions can be created in multiple ways, but the easiest is with the `raddb/clients.conf` file (or `freeradius/clients.conf` on debian).

A client entry that'd match your SQL record would be:

```
client hlg-vpn {
    ipaddr = 127.16.2.10
    secret = testing
}
```

If you want to continue using SQL based clients, then check the `read_clients` pair in the sql module's config is uncommented and set to yes:

- https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/mods-available/sql#L245
- https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/sql.conf#L108

and that the `sql` module is listed/uncommented in at least one `authorize`, `accounting`, `post-auth` etc... section. Or is listed in the `instantiate {}` section in `raddb/radiusd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that the "server" field for each NAS is filled out and matches the virtual-server with which this NAS is to be used.  If you only have the "default" virtual server enabled in "sites-enabled" then set this field to "default".